# Setting the font-size of a body tag

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to configure a basic CSS template that I can use to start working with REM. I see the method of setting the following `body { font-size: 62.5% };` so that the math is easier (1rem = 10px as 16px is the default font-size).

I'm not sure I like this way as it involves having to specify the size of `<h1>`-`<h6>` as well as `<p>` tags if a font-size of 10px isn't my baseline.

I've been experimenting with some different ways and have been very confused with how `px` and `%` relates in terms of font size. Take the following example:

```
<html>

<body>

  <header>
    <h1>Testing h1</h1>
    <h2>Testing h2</h2>
  </header>

  <main>
    <p>Random paragraph</p>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Consider the following css:

```
body {
 font-size: 100%;
}
```

I expected the browser to render font in their default size, which is 16px. Anything in a `<p>` tag is 16px still, but `<h1>` - `<h6>` revert to their original size as specified in the browser stylesheet. Why isn't ALL text set to 16px?

Another example:

```
body {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

Why doesn't `<h1>`-`<h6>` take this font size of `12px`? `<h1>`-`<h6>`  does get smaller (by 75% as 12/16 = 0.75). I'd expect h1 to be either 12px or stay the same default value because the value specified for h1-h6 in the user agent stylesheets is MORE specific.

How do the rules work in terms of specifying percentages? What is the best practice in terms of setting up a stylesheet so that REM can be used?

Comment: Why dont you use [Normalize CSS](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) first

Comment: I should have pointed out I actually do use normalize.css. I don't see how this will make a difference to anything though? Normalize.css doesn't do anything to font sizes from what I saw.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`h1` has a default `font-size` set to `2em` which means `2 x the font size of the parent element`. Same thing with the others headings, they all have a `font-size` specified using `em` unit.

[image]

Using percentage with `font-size` is also relative to parent `font-size` and means `p x the font size of the parent element` where `p` is a value between `0` (for 0%) and `1` (for 100%).

So if you specify `100%` within the body then the body will have `16px` (the default `font-size`) and `h1` will have `32px`.

<sup>You can use the same logic to find the `font-size` for the other headings.</sup>

```css
body {
  font-size:100%;
}
```

```html
<h1>this a text</h1>
```

If you specify `12px` within the body then the `h1` will have `24px`

```css
body {
  font-size:12px;
}
```

```html
<h1>this a text</h1>
```

And specifiying `62.5%` will make the body to have `10px` and the `h1` `20px`

```css
body {
  font-size:62.5%;
}
```

```html
<h1>this a text</h1>
```

And since `p` has no default value for `font-size` it will simply inherit the value specified within the body.

You can easily check those values in the computed tab using the dev tools:

[image]

---

From the [documenation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size):

> The size of an em value is dynamic. When defining the font-size
> property, an em **is equal to the size of the font that applies to the**
> **parent** of the element in question. If you haven't set the font size
> anywhere on the page, then it is the browser default, which is often
> 16px

And for percentage:

> A positive `<percentage>` value, relative to the parent element's font size.

Comment: This is such a detailed answer, thanks very much for that, especially pointing out the default values of `h1-h6`. When dealing with REM, the way I've set my baseline is for the body tag to have a font-size of 100%, and for responsiveness, I've set some breakpoints where the font-size changes to 75% and 60% at `max-width: 768px` and `max-width: 410px`; respectively. Would this be a good approach?

Comment: @ftahir good or bad is probably opinion based ... if it's working fine and their is no conflict then it's good but if you have some issue then you should probably re-think it ... simply pay attention to not use very small font-size, I think we should avoid having less than 14px because it can be diffuclt to read for some person

Answer (score 4):

### The `rem` is relative to `HTML`, not `BODY`

The `rem` unit is based on the font size of the `HTML` element, not the `BODY` element. So you should set base font size this way:

```css
HTML {font-size: 62.5%; } /* Now `rem` is equivalent to `10px` */
```

instead of

```css
BODY {font-size: 62.5%; } /* Does NOT affect `rem` */
```

### HTML font size may affect scrolling speed

Note that at least in some browsers, font size of the `HTML` element affects the wheel-scrolling step size: the smaller the font size of the `HTML` element is, the smaller the step size is and the slower scrolling is.

### Resetting font size for all elements

To reset font size for all elements, you can use the universal selector:

```html
* {font-size: 100%; }
```

or:

```html
* {font-size: 1em; }
```

### Proper `DOCTYPE` for cross-browser consistency

Also, make sure you have the proper [`DOCTYPE`](http://tanalin.com/en/blog/2011/04/html5-doctype/) declaration in the beginning of your HTML document to turn the standards-compliance mode on for the document for consistent cross-browser rendering and behavior:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Answer (score 3):

> Why doesn't `<h1>-<h6>` take this font size of 12px?

`<h1>` and related elements don't change their font size to be the same as their ancestor when you change their ancestor's font size simply because their default font size (in the stylesheet built into the browser) is not set to `100%`, `1em`, `inherit` or similar and you haven't specified a different font size to override the one supplied by the browser.

> `<h1>-<h6>` does get smaller (by 75% as 12/16 = 0.75). I'd expect h1 to be either 12px or stay the same default value because the value specified for h1-h6 in the user agent stylesheets is MORE specific.

The value specified in the browser stylesheet (in my browser at least) uses the `em` unit, so it is **proportional** (double in the case of `<h1>`) to the font size of the parent element.

> How do the rules work in terms of specifying percentages?

The choice of unit you use for the font size of an ancestor element (`px`, `%` or anything else) is irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You said "...and you haven't specified a different font size to override the one supplied by the browser." I thought that the body tag would override the default browser stylesheet (even `h` tags) due to the fact that stylesheets cascade. However, I think I missed precedence here. Would I be correct in saying that this is not the case because in the browser stylesheet, the `h1` property is a more specific selector than `body`, and specificity takes precedence over less specific rules that appear later?

Comment: @ftahir it's not about specifity here but inheritance ... since there is a value specified within h1 than this one will be used unless there is a more specific selector  to override this (and body is not one of them! beause it's not selecting h1) BUT if no value is specified then you will inherit the value of the parent element which is the body

Comment: "I thought that the body tag would override the default browser stylesheet (even h tags) due to the fact that stylesheets cascade." — The cascade handles the order in which rules are applied when multiple, conflicting rules are applied to the same element. A rule targetting `body` is not targetting `h1` at all, so the cascade isn't relevant.

Comment: "the h1 property is a more specific selector than body" — `h1` and `body` are equally specific. You haven't specified a rule for `h1` at all.

Comment: Aha okay, that makes more sense now regarding cascading. So in the case of `font-size:12px;` for `body`, `h1` isn't actually being affected _explicitly_, but because it's defined by relational values (`em`), then if `body`'s font size changes, then `h1` will also change because `body` is the closest ancestor with a defined font-size? If that's correct then I think I understand this.

Comment: @ftahir — Every element will have a defined font size. The `body` is just the only one defined *by you*.

Comment: @Quentin, understood, but the `h1` tag is defined in `em` by default, meaning it will be proportional to the ancestor with the closest _absolute_ `font-size` value, which in this case, is the `body` tag, if I understood correctly

Comment: @ftahir — It is proportional to the parent element. That element might be proportional to its parent, but it doesn't really help to think in those terms. If it is `200%` then it is double it's parent's font size. If its parent is also `200%` then it is 4 times it's grandparent. And thinking "200% -> proportional to grandparent" is just going to risk you thinking it is double, not 4 times, the grandparent.

Comment: Makes a lot more sense now, thanks for the help - much appreciated :) Sorry it took me a while to get there!

Answer (score -3):

It's just working fine on my side. The only possibility could be that, the link to css file is missing in your HTML... :)
Otherwise, just to make sure, try inline style for same property.